# Modules being ignored

Tags: drivers, bbswitch

```
/etc/modules includes

bbswitch load_state=0
```

Every time, `bbswitch` isn't loaded, and I have to manually:

```
sudo modprobe bbswitch
```

Then run `bbswitch` command to toggle graphics card.

Why isn't it respecting `load_state=0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing what distribution you are using, the following does apply at least for Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, since Ubuntu started to use `systemd` from 16.04 onwards.

The old module-loader script `/etc/init.d/kmod` would allow to put module options into `/etc/modules`. `systemd` did replace this script with an own service `systemd-modules-load.service`. The new method does not allow putting module options into `/etc/modules` and only accepts the module names each per line.
If you call `/etc/init.d/kmod` it will not execute the script but rather call the `systemd` service `systemd-modules-load.service`. Further it is better to get used to `systemd` as it is very unlikely that the old sys-v init scripts will ever experience a comeback and will rather be completely replaced.

However, if you want to load the `bbswitch` module with a set of options you have to do the steps as follows.

Make the module load at boot time.

```
root@localhost:~# echo "bbswitch" >> /etc/modules
```

Put your options into a `/etc/modprobe.d` file which is honored each time  a module is loaded. So this should be even better to define module parameters. So create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/bbswitch.conf` and put in the line as follows.

```
root@localhost:~# cat /etc/modprobe.d/bbswitch.conf
options bbswitch load_state=0
```